# Invoke method on server from client using RMI

Tags: client, rmi

I have been provided with URL to connect to server and its function.

example of URL: `rmi://(host):(port)/rul`e

example of function: `reloadRule()`

Basically, I need to invoke this reloadRule function from client side. I tried using java RMI and creating the rmiClient class and interface.

This is my code:

**Interface**

```
import java.rmi.Remote;
     import java.rmi.RemoteException;

     public interface RmiServerIntf extends Remote{
           public void reloadRule() throws RemoteException;
     }
```

**Client**

```
import java.rmi.Naming;

     public class RmiClient {
            RmiServerIntf obj = null; 

            public void reloadRule() { 
                 try { 
                   obj = (RmiServerIntf)Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost:8009/rule");
                   obj.reloadRule(); 
                 } catch (Exception e) { 
                   System.err.println("RmiClient exception: " + e); 
                   e.printStackTrace(); 
                 } 
            }     
     }
```

**Java Class to call the rmiClient**

```
// invoke RMI service

        // Create and install a security manager
        /*
        if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
            System.setSecurityManager(new NullRMISecurityManager());
        } */
        RmiClient cli = new RmiClient();
        cli.reloadRule();
        System.out.println("Reload Rule");
```

I'm still confused how to run this things? I tried run the class that call rmiClient, and get this exception:

> java.security.AccessControlException: access denied
>   (java.lang.RuntimePermission setContextClassLoader)
>           at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:374)
>           at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
>           at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
>           at java.lang.Thread.setContextClassLoader(Thread.java:1394)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:874)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
>           Exception in thread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]" 
>   java.security.AccessControlException: access denied
>   (java.lang.RuntimePermission setContext
>            ClassLoader)
>            at  java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:374)
>           at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
>           at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
>           at java.lang.Thread.setContextClassLoader(Thread.java:1394)
>           at  org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1574)
>           at  org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1559)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Can please shed some light and point me to right direction. Thanks.

---

**Update**

I have removed the security manager and got this exception:

```
    RmiClient exception: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiInvocationHandler (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiInvocationHandler (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Naming.java:84)
```

Something missing in my code? What this error means?

---

**Update 2**

I include spring-2.5.4.jar in the library. I got this exception then:

```
      RmiClient exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy10 cannot be cast to admin.fsms.RmiServerIntf
      java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy10 cannot be cast to admin.fsms.RmiServerIntf
```

The source of problem is in here:

```
      obj = (RmiServerIntf)Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost:8009/rule");
```

I should call interface in rmi client right? Why it can't be cast? Something wrong with the interface?

Comment: Why the security manager? Just remove it.

Comment: Hi EJP, thanks alot for the response. I have updated my first post. Removed the security manager and got the exception. Can please help again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will either have to:

1. Install the Spring JAR files at the client (to fix that `ClassNotFoundException`)
2. Use the codebase feature (ditto), which also implies restoring a SecurityManager, although you certainly shouldn't write your own: use the `RMISecurityManager` and write a proper .policy file, or
3. Use straight RMI instead of Spring to export the remote object (to eliminate the underlying cause). I don't know anything about Spring but just make your remote object extend `UnicastRemoteObject` and `rebind()` it to the Registry yourself.

Comment: for no 3, you mean extend UnicastRemoteObject in the server side? Because it's someone else's work and I can't modify it. for no 1, I search from internet for this jar. I get this link [link](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiInvocationHandler). I'm not sure which one I should download. Just choose one of it will do?

Comment: The remote object and what it extends live on the server side. If it's someone else's work there should already be a working client and client configuration. If there isn't, somebody else's work is incomplete and/or incorrect and will have to be completed, extended, fixed, whatever it takes. I don't know whether that link is kidding by listing about 50 JAR files but this is evidence of a larger problem, not a solution.

Comment: EJP, thanks for your help. I've talked to the person that create the server application and he changes from his side so I can call the method using straight RMI. It's working now.